# How can I close activity without showing splash screen again?

Tags: android, splash-screen

I am making a splash screen and need help closing this activity so if a user presses the 'BACK' button they go back to the home screen, NOT the splash screen...

```
package com.Sosotech;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

public class Splashscrn extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splashscrn);

        Handler x = new Handler();
        x.postDelayed(new SplashHandler(), 5000);

    }

 class SplashHandler implements Runnable {
     public void run() {
         startActivity(new Intent(getApplication(), Main.class));



     }
 }

}
```

PS: I just want to know if it is possible to make the splash screen come up every time the app is resumed. I will not be implementing this, I just wondered how it would be done.

Comment: Why would you want to show the splash screen after application resume? The idea of the splash screen is to show it on application start, not resume.

Comment: I wouldn't want to. I'm asking if it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close the activity:

```
Splashscrn.this.finish();
```

*For your PS*
Set the activity as your main, launching activity and set clearTaskOnLaunch to true in the manifest.

Comment: Could you please explain what each bit of that will do?

Comment: "Set the activity as your main, launching activity and set clearTaskOnLaunch to true in the manifest." --- Is that for my PS bit or for the main question?

Answer (score 1):

use finish() as:

startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main.class));

finish();

Comment: Alright, why should I use this rather than 'Splashscrn.this.finish();' out of interest?

Comment: both works in the same way actually...Splashscrn.this.finish() is making sure of the reference.....